# How to restore the state of a fragment in view pager, if fragment is not getting added in back stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `activity A` and `activity B`. And in my manifest file, i have set its launch mode as a Single Task to maintain only one instance of each activity. In both the activities I am using three fragments with `ViewPager`. Now, here is the problem, when I fill all the fields of all fragments of `activity A`, then move to `activity B`, then the data filled in the fragments of `activity A` gets removed. So, how can we restore the state of fragments?

```
//Global Declaration
Intent i =null;

//method i used in fragment to save the value of fields.

@Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
                i.putExtra("customerId", _customerId);
                i.putExtra("panCardName", _panCardName);
                i.putExtra("panCardAcknowledgementNmber", _panCardAcknowledgementNmber);
                i.putExtra("natureOfBusiness", _natureOfBusiness);
                i.putExtra("annualTurnover", _annualTurnover);
                i.putExtra("networth", _networth);
                i.putExtra("occupation", _occupation);
                i.putExtra("date", _date);
}

//method in fragment, where i retrieve the saved values.

 public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        i = getActivity().getIntent();
        if(i != null) {
            _customerId = i.getStringExtra("customerId");
            _panCardName = i.getStringExtra("panCardName");
            _panCardAcknowledgementNmber = i.getStringExtra("panCardAcknowledgementNmber");
            _natureOfBusiness = i.getStringExtra("natureOfBusiness");
            _annualTurnover = i.getStringExtra("annualTurnover");
            _networth = i.getStringExtra("networth");

_occupation = i.getStringExtra("occupation");
            _date = i.getStringExtra("date");
        }
```

Comment: Please do not use so much **bold** and *italics* in your question as it is difficult to read, and tends to annoy many of the regulars here. Furthermore, you have posted no code at all; we prefer a [mcve] so that we can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: okay. Sorry for that. Now i have updated my answer. onResume() always return null.

Comment: @KenY-N Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to use

```
int counter  = 0;
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putInt("value",counter);
}
```

for saving the value in fragment,

and retaining the data like below code,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setRetainInstance(true);        
}
```

and onCreateView() method

```
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   if (savedInstanceState != null) {
          int count = savedInstanceState.getInt("value");
          Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(count) ,    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

Comment: i cannot use setRetainInstance(true),  because onCreate() invokes only at the time of creating an activity. And my activity is created only once.